# Is it possible to prove that a relation is a function or not by using derivative?

Tags: functions

There several ways to prove if a mathematical formula is a function or not :

*First:* To find 2 or more $X$'s that have the same $Y$ assigned to them .

*Second:* To assume that we put $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ into the formula and then come to the conclusion that $y_1=y_2$ .

But I've heard that there's even a third way which is using derivative to determine if a relation is a function or not . Honestly I cannot use the 2 provided ways efficiently in a reasonable time , when things get complicated as bellow :

- Determine if bellow formulas are function or not :

  1. $F(X-2)=|X|-1$
  2. $F(|X|-1)=2X+1$
  3. $F(|X|-1)=2X^2 +1$
  4. $F(2X^2 +1)=|X|-1$
  5. $Y!=X$
  6. $Y= X + [X]$
- For what amount of a , the below is representing a function ?
  $$(Y-X^2)( (X-2)^2 + (Y+a) ) = 0$$

Many thanks

Mohammad from Iran

Comment: I've edited your post to put the formulas in Latex and use MathJax lists/enumeration. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: It would help to know the intended domain, codomain.